# Facebook login App

Tags: facebook, authentication

I am trying to create my websites FACEBOOK LOGIN, the App is NOT MY BAG. I keep getting this error message:

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have something listed in app domain in your Dev App settings (http://developers.facebook.com/apps) that is different from the URL that you are trying to redirect to?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your API settings... Change the call back url to the folder where u have placed all the files on the server. And also the important thing is that you gotta host that page on the server first and check whether it works properly on not... The facebook cant revert Back if you have placed the files on your system.  Let me know if you need more clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download Facebook sdk v4 first and paste below code in your php file:

```
session_start();
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
// init app with app id (APPID) and secret (SECRET)
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('your_app_id','your_secret_key');
// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://www.yahoo.com/' );
try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
}
// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
    // graph api request for user data
    $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
    $response = $request->execute();
    // get response
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
    // print data
    echo print_r( $graphObject, 1 );
} else {
    // show login url
    echo 'getLoginUrl() . '">Login';
}
```